# Gradient color issue when converting from pptx to images. Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

**I have created pptx and ppt converter to images using apache poi but while converting some file i have an exception after two or three converts.**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red

Main converter from both pptx and ppt

```
 import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("working");

        String directory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/";

        //creating an empty presentation
        File file=new File(directory + "test6.pptx");
        String fileName = file.getName();
        // Identify the file whether it is ppt or pptx
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(directory +  fileName);

        if (extension.equals("pptx")) {


            XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow(inputStream);

            //getting the dimensions and size of the slide
            Dimension pgsize = pptx.getPageSize();
            java.util.List<XSLFSlide> pptxSlide = Arrays.asList(pptx.getSlides());

            for (int i = 0; i < pptxSlide.size(); i++) {
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                Graphics2D graphics = createImage(img, pgsize);
                //render
                pptxSlide.get(i).draw(graphics);
                graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOver);
                graphics.setPaint(Color.WHITE);

                //creating an image file as output
                imageFile(i, img);


                graphics.dispose();

            }


        }else if(extension.equals("ppt")){


            SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);

            //getting the dimensions and size of the slide
            Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
            List<Slide> slide = Arrays.asList(ppt.getSlides());

            for (int i = 0; i < slide.size(); i++) {
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                //render
                slide.get(i).draw(createImage(img, pgsize));


                //creating an image file as output
                imageFile(i, img);
            }
        }else {
            throw new Exception("Not compatible type ");
        }
    }

    private static void imageFile(int i, BufferedImage img) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ppt_image_" + i + ".png");
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
        System.out.println("Image successfully created");
        out.close();
    }


    private static Graphics2D createImage(BufferedImage img, Dimension pgsize){
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

        //clear the drawing area
        graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
        // default rendering options
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOver);


        return graphics;
    }
}
```

> The main problem is that I want to convert any pptx file any kind of with gradient or simple colors to images.

Converted gradient slide [greyed]

[image: It is grey color but in fact it is gradient]

Comment: Please open a bug report on our [bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI) - component "SL Common" and attach your example file. I'll take care of it or at least give you feedback there.

Comment: Havent reported a bug before in bugzilla but tried link: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63460 @kiwiwings

Comment: Please provide the .pptx instead of the .png @Aliy

Comment: Done added pptx file to the bug report @kiwiwings

Comment: any news ? i have uploaded pptx file ? @kiwiwings

Comment: Your provided file is not throwing the error. I'm using the trunk version of POI, which should be similar to the latest released stable version. I've tested with the PPTX2PNG class and also with the code you've provided ... in your case, I would also use PPTX2PNG, because your code produces white images.
I guess the failing file is "test6.pptx" instead of "test7.pptx".

Comment: could you share your code via github? i wanna test it myself @kiwiwings and thank you

Comment: I use the junit test [TestPPTX2PNG](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/TestPPTX2PNG.java) with  `basedir = new File("<path to .pptx directory")` and `files = "test7.pptx"` .... @Aliy